# What algorithm to use for parallel dense matrix inversion on at most 8 cores?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, parallel-computing

I need to implement parallel dense matrix inversion for a language I am using that appears to not have an existing library for this (specifically IDL using IDL Bridge for message passing). I am familiar with parallel programming methods through experience using MPI in C++, though mainly for parallel FFT and N-body methods. I have little experience or knowledge of computational methods, serial or parallel, for linear algebra.

What I am looking for is a clear pseudo code description of a robust, stable parallel matrix inversion algorithm that is appropriate for a small number of cores as the machine that runs the (currently serial) IDL task has 8 cores. In practice I will probably use only 4 to keep cores free for other tasks.

I'd favour simplicity over bleeding edge performance if there are a range of well known algorithms for this task.

Comment: I assume you mean _dense_ matrices. Surely you can make IDL use a threaded implementation of LAPACK (e.g., MKL or even ATLAS), using `LD_PRELOAD` if necessary.

Comment: Yes thanks, I am after a dense matrix algorithm. I've clarified that now in the question. I'll investigate threaded LAPACK implementations as you suggest. That would be preferable if possible. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: IDL has had multithreaded linear algebra libraries for at least the last 3 or 4 years.  I believe that LA_INVERT will run multithreaded on any recent version of IDL.  Note that there's a configuration switch that controls how many threads are available (and it's probably set to single threaded by default)

Comment: Thanks Brian. I've checked the documentation of both IDL7 and IDL8 and neither suggest LA_INVERT uses the thread pool. I've also tested that when I set IDL to invert large matrices for a while only 1 of the 8 cores gets used (according to my system monitor). I've checked the settings of !CPU and TPOOL_NTHREADS is equal to HW_NCPU which according to the documentation means threaded routines should be able to use as many cores as are physically available. I've also tried reducing TPOOL_MIN_ELTS to enforce multi-threading in LA_INVERT with no luck. Any more ideas?

Comment: How large are your matrices?  IDL won't use multithreading unless the matrices are large enough.  If you've got matrices that are too small (say less than N=1000) then there won't be any performance advantages to going multithreaded and IDL won't use the multithreaded routines.  There are configuration settings for this cutoff as well.  I haven't used IDL in several years, but I'm really surprised that this isn't working for you- I'd suggest asking in an IDL specific forum.  The comp.lang.idl=pvwave usenet gr be a good place to look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of rolling your own, I would suggest you have a look at existing robust and efficient parallel implementations such as [PLASMA](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/plasma/).

If you're only looking for algorithms to implement yourself, most of the routines are documented excessively in the "Documentation" section of that site.